# Load Zurb Foundation tooltips 4.2 on an element within an ajax loaded colorbox modal window

Tags: ajax, colorbox, zurb-foundation, tooltip

I am trying to load Zurb Foundation tooltips 4.2 on an element within an ajax loaded colorbox modal window. I have tried everything I can think of but I just can not get this working. I have tried reloading, re initializing the framework within the ajax page, including all libraries in the ajax page, I even tried reloading the tooltips in the onComplete method of colorbox. Nothing works. I have searched for answers but it seems all previous posts are using a different syntax, I assume an older version of foundation.

I know I am loading it properly on the calling page because I put a test link on the page and the tooltip shows perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is how I tried to load it using the onComplete method:

```
        $.colorbox({href:'/controller/action', 
                    className: 'create-account',
                    width: '500px',
                    onComplete:function(){
                    $(document).foundation('tooltips','reload');
                     _setUpDialogs();
                    }
        });
```

Comment: So it turned out to be a z-index issue. We raised the z-index and the tooltips showed up. Thanks anyways!!